# BIRT runtime 4.6.0 batch file not running

Tags: batch-file, jar, runtime, birt

Trying to run a batch file on the latest version of BIRT. Upgraded from 3.7.1 to 4.6.0. The .bat file is exactly the same (other than changing the BIRT_HOME system variable).

The steps I took were as follows:

1. Downloaded 4.6.0 from an official mirror
2. Copied 2 jar files across into the BIRT_HOME/ReportEngine/lib folder. These jar files are jtds.jar and ojdbc6.jar so I can connect to an external database
3. Copied over my .bat file, report design file and report properties file
4. Edited the .bat file to give the correct location to BIRT_HOME
5. Executed the .bat file from command line

The error I get is:

`Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner`

The contents of my .bat file are:

```
@echo off
set BIRT_HOME=C:\birt-460\ReportEngine\
call %BIRT_HOME%genReport.bat -m runrender -o "output.PDF" -f PDF -F "reportproperties.properties" "reportproperties.rptDesign"
```

I can confirm that the following JAR file is present in my /lib folders: org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar

The part I'm struggling with is that these steps work in 3.7.1 and 4.2.2, but not 4.6.0

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The error does not look like it is coming from the code you posted so without seeing any of the other code it is really hard to make any suggestions.

Comment: That's all it says when running the .bat in a command window. Is there a way to increase the logging that's produced?

Comment: You are only showing us the code of your .BAT file.  But, your bat file is calling another .BAT file which in turn is calling a JAVA program.  Do you see my point now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497356) in the 4.6.0 BIRT release.

As a workaround, simply remove the `ECLIPSE_.RSA` and `ECLIPSE_.SF`, from the *META-INF/* folder in **`org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar`**, which is in *$BIRT_HOME/ReportEngine/lib/*.

---

Refs: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1086829/

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the BIRT 4.9 runtime.
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.birt